# Чем отличаются контекстно свободные грамматики от контекстно несвободных?

Tags: грамматика, синтаксис

Добрый день, уважаемые посетители сообщества "Русский язык".

Такой вопрос возник у меня, в связи с тем, что я начал изучать формы Бэкуса-Науэра по статьям в Интернете.
В статьях постоянно упоминаются термины "контекстно-свободный", "формальный язык", и тому подобные.

Возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Чем собственно формальный язык (синтаксис, грамматика) отличается от "неформального" (и существуют ли вообще неформальные языки/грамматики)?
2. Чем контекстно-свободная грамматика отличается от контекстно-несвободной (и, аналогично первому вопросу, существуют ли вообще подобные грамматики)?
3. Какие символы принято считать терминальными символами алфавита, а какие не-терминальными? По какому критерию проводится водораздел?

Буду рад любой информации.
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю Вашего уровня погружения в проблему и сам оперирую в общем-то азами. 
Попробую ответить на этом уровне.

> Чем собственно формальный язык (синтаксис, грамматика) отличается от "неформального" (и существуют ли вообще неформальные языки/грамматики)?

Формальный язык - язык, семантика которого вытекает только из описания самого языка. 
Среди естественных языков, строго говоря, формальных нет. Искусственные языки всегда задумываются как формальные, но реализуются с разной степенью приближения. Языки программирования - формальные по определению. Хотя встречаются некоторые казусы, но это уже вопрос реализаций.

> Чем контекстно-свободная грамматика отличается от контекстно-несвободной (и, аналогично первому вопросу, существуют ли вообще подобные грамматики)?

Именно что аналогично. У контекстно-независимых грамматик правила построения высказывания и его смысл не зависят от предшествующих высказываний. Как следствие, контекстно-свободная грамматика задается (в идеале) некоторым конечным числом правил, чего никогда нельзя сделать для грамматик естественных языков.

Следует еще добавить, что применительно к грамматикам естественных языков все эти термины применимы, строго говоря, не к грамматикам как таковым, а к некоторым описаниям реально существующих грамматик, т.е. абстрактным моделям. В этом вообще разница в понимании слова "грамматика" применительно к языкам общения и языкам программирования.

Повторяю, касательно обоих ответов, это совсем не строгие определения, а некоторое понятийное представление.

> Какие символы принято считать терминальными символами алфавита, а какие не-терминальными? По какому критерию проводится водораздел?

А вот это уже вопрос подхода автора. "Водораздел" проводят каждый в меру своего понимания и рассматриваемой модели. (*Если конечно, в недавнее время не договорились о какой-то общности, я давно бросил следить за этим направлением*). Но в любом случае "терминальный" здесь в значении "атомарный", "неразложимый"; это в известном смысле можно считать ответом на вопрос.

Ногами не бить, отвечаю как дилетант дилетанту.

Answer (score 0):

Почему ж Вы обращаетесь в группу" Русский язык "с вопросом по математической лингвистике и информатике? Если Вы занялись этим как новичок, можно почитать сначала хотя бы Википедию, там как раз термины объясняются.
  http://www.ngpedia.ru/id627159p1.html
 http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0
•   http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB
http://www.wikiznanie.ru/ru-wz/index.php/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA
А разобраться в этом помогут математики и программисты, но не русаки.